# how I can initialize a parameter in AMPL when it is defined on multiple sets?

Tags: optimization, ampl

Suppose I have

```
param m; #number of modes
 param n; #number of individual
param a; #number of alternatives
param f; #number of household
set M, default{1..m}; #set of modes
set N, default{1..n}; #set of individuals
set A, default{1..a}; #set of alternatives
set F, default{1..f}; #set of family
set E, within F cross N
```

How I can initialize param X{E,M,A} ?

Suppose

```
a:=2 , m:=3 , n:= 4 f:=2;
```

and set E is defined:

```
 set E:= 1 1   1 2    2 3    2 4 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the parameter just as you suggested:

```
param X{E,M,A};
```

Now, if you want to provide a default value (which I assume is what you are asking), you can do it in the usual way:

```
param X{E,M,A} default 0;
```

Then provide some non-default values in the `.dat` file, e.g.,:

```
param: X :=
    1 1 1 2   5
    2 3 2 1   6;
```

Note that AMPL doesn't fill the default values into the parameter until you call `solve`. From the [AMPL book](https://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/10-params.pdf), p. 120:

> The expression that gives the default value of a parameter is evaluated only when the parameter’s value is first needed, such as when an objective or constraint that uses the parameter is processed by a `solve` command.

So if you type `display X;` after you have issued the `model` and `data` commands but before you have issued the `solve` command, you'll only get the non-default values, e.g.:

```
X :=
1 1 1 2   5
2 3 2 1   6
;
```

But if you use `display X;` after you call `solve`, you'll get the full list:

```
X [1,*,*,1] (tr)
:   1   2    :=
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   0   0

 [1,*,*,2] (tr)
:   1   2    :=
1   5   0
2   0   0
3   0   0

 [2,*,*,1] (tr)
:   3   4    :=
1   0   0
2   6   0
3   0   0

 [2,*,*,2] (tr)
:   3   4    :=
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   0   0
;
```

---

For completeness, here are the `.mod` and `.dat` files I used for this answer:

**.mod:**

```
param m; #number of modes
param n; #number of individual
param a; #number of alternatives
param f; #number of household
set M, default{1..m}; #set of modes
set N, default{1..n}; #set of individuals
set A, default{1..a}; #set of alternatives
set F, default{1..f}; #set of family
set E, within F cross N;

param X{E,M,A} default 0;
var myVar{E,M,A} >= 0;

minimize Obj: sum {(i,j) in E, mm in M, aa in A} X[i,j,mm,aa] * myVar[i,j,mm,aa];
```

**.dat:**

```
param a:=2;
param m:=3;
param n:= 4;
param f:=2;
set E:= 1 1   1 2    2 3    2 4 ; 

param: X :=
    1 1 1 2   5
    2 3 2 1   6;
```

Comment: sorry I meant X{E,M,A}, I am sorry

Comment: your param X is 4 dimensional?

Comment: It is three dimensional but one of the dimensions (`E`) has 2 dimensions.

Comment: I couldn't understand how param X has been defined! how is its 3 dimensions? I mean which indices is for what set?

Comment: `X` is indexed by 3 sets. But because one of the sets itself is the cross product of 2 sets, the total number of indices is 4. You can think of it like `X[(f,n),m,a]`, but in AMPL syntax, you don't put the `(` and `)`, so it's just `X[f,n,m,a]`.

Comment: I mean 5 and 6 is corresponding to which set?

Comment: 5 and 6 are the values of `X`. In other words, `X[1,1,1,2] = 5` and `X[2,3,2,1] = 6`.